# Error trying to load javascript script in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to load a javascript I created for using it in mongoDB. I've tried many sintaxes as `load('path/file')` and still the same error as it folows:

```
> load("/Scripts/logs_js.js")
```

`2020-03-31T17:33:32.671+0200 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't open file :
@/Scripts/logs_js.js:1:15
@(shell):1:1
2020-03-31T17:33:32.671+0200 E  QUERY    [js] Error: error loading js file: /Scripts/logs_js.js :
@(shell):1:1`

I'm desperate about this error, I've seen people doing the same way as me and it works for them. Thanks everyone beforehand.

Comment: looks like you are doing that within shell. You should run it outside shell, so something like this: `mongo /Scripts/logs_js.js`, or if it's dumped records then do `mongoimport /Scripts/logs_js.js`

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that mongo was correctly opening the javascript file. But in the first line of my javascript there was a cat() function to open a .txt file, and that was the one that couldn't be opened.